# SQL concat and escape characters

Tags: sql, oracle, escaping

So, I am working on a query which would get applicant's first_name_txt, last_name_txt or business business_name.

I am facing a problem while trying to concatenate the comma.

```
 case
 when (credit_req_contr_requestor.requestor_type_id=0)
 then CONCAT(CONCAT(credit_req_contr_requestor.last_name_txt,'','') , 
 credit_req_contr_requestor.first_name_txt )
when(requestor_business.requestor_type_id=3)
 then    requestor_business.business_name_txt end as applicant_name_txt
```

The reason I am giving two single quotes is because this query is run by a java sql loader, that breaks when it encounters a single quote.

But, when I run this query, it gives an error saying "invalid number of arguements". So, I added three single quotes `''','''` , but then applicant_name_txt would appear as `Smith',' John`.

I tried using || instead of concat, and it is the same issue there as well.

How do I get about this? How do I add that comma in between those two fields while displaying? Any other escape characters I can use?

Comment: i hope you are not complaining that `mystring = 'select ... 'bla' ...'` is not working - because in that case you should escape [Java String characters](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/characters.html), not SQL - i.e. `'... \'bla\' ...'` or `"... 'bla' ..."`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need to completely avoid the use of a single quote (it seems very odd that a utility would break if fed a SQL statement that contains a string literal) you can do something like this

```
SQL> ed
Wrote file afiedt.buf

  1  with x as (
  2    select 0 type_id, 'John' first_name, 'Smith' last_name, null business_name
  3      from dual
  4    union all
  5    select 3, null, null, 'ACME Bolts'
  6      from dual
  7  )
  8  select (case when type_id = 0
  9               then last_name || chr(44) || chr(32) || first_name
 10               else business_name
 11           end)
 12*   from x
SQL> /

(CASEWHENTY
-----------
Smith, John
ACME Bolts
```

Comment: this query is parsed by a java sql loader, which cuts the string short when it encounters the single quote, and hence the reason I am trying to use escape characters.

Answer (score 1):

How about 
CONCAT(credit_req_contr_requestor.last_name_txt,CHR(44))